# Check the sum of array must be less than maximum time

Tags: java, arrays

Check if the sum of array is less than maximum time and if yes then the generator of the random numbers will stop and the output will be like this:

```
No of customer = 3     
max time = 4;          
customer 1 = 3     
customer 2 = 1          
total time = 4          
//so the customer 3 a
```

class CstplangsBadango

```
package cstplangsbadango;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CstplangsBadango {


    static int customer = 0;
    static int maxTime = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter number of customer: ");
        customer = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of Maximum time: ");
        maxTime = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");

        int[] cust = new int[customer];
        int j = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int chu = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cust.length; i++) {

            cust[i] = (int) randomFill();

            j += 1;
            sum += cust[i];
            System.out.println("Customer #" + j + " = " + cust[i]);    

        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Maximum time: " + sum);


    }

    public static double randomFill() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        return randomNum;
    }

    }
```

Comment: customer 3 is then removed because by the time customer 2 reached the counter it consumes already 4 which is the max time

Comment: Do you have a question? You just stated your homework problem and posted some code, but it looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: wheres the problem? please specify what problem you currently have..

Comment: How to compare the sum of the arrays on the maximum time and then if it reaches the max time then it will stop on the for loop. sorry >-< but the sample output is stated thanks hope you help me

Comment: @JeraldBadango since the max time is a non changing value you will want it to be `final MAX_TIME = 4;`

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < cust.length; i++) {
    cust[i] = (int) randomFill();
}

for (int i = 0; i < cust.length; i++) { 
    int newSum = sum + cust[i];

    if (sum < maxTime) {
        sum = newSum;
    } else if(sum == maxTime) {
        sum = newSum;
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }

    j++;
    System.out.println("Customer #" + j + " = " + cust[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must exclude your statement

```
j+=1;
sum += cust[i];
System.out.println("Customer #" + j + " = " + cust[i])
```

and create another loop below your created loop when you fill your array

```
for(int i=0;i<cust.length;++i)
{
        j+=1;
        sum+=cust[i];
        if(sum>=MAX_TIME)
        {
           i=cust.length;
           System.out.println("Customer #" + j + " = " + cust[i]);
        }

}

if(sum>MAX_TIME)
{
   int subtractor=sum-MAX_TIME;
   sum-=subtractor;
}
```

Comment: Whenever i type an odd value of maximum time the total time exceed the maximum time...

Comment: @JeraldBadango do you want the total time to not exceed the maximum time?

Comment: Yes but the total time displayed exceeded the maximum time

Comment: @JeraldBadango you might want to add a variable that will set the total time right `int subtractor;`    `subtractor=totalTime-MAX_TIME;`  `totalTime-=substractor;`

Comment: it's displaying a negative value of the total time